# How can I use D3 to graph configuration items and their dependencies?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, configuration-management, change-management, itil

I'm a new user to D3 and am trying to think about how to best implement a mapping of our configuration items.

What I'm looking for is essentially a treemap (I think) but with inter-related dependencies.

### The Data

I'm working with ITIL-style configuration items, so logical services, applications, machines, etc. that make up an IT service that we offer to our customers.

The JSON data I'd be providing is going to come from a WebAPI service that I am defining and so the data can be returned however is necessary.

### The Goal

I need to get across:

- **The name** of the configuration item ("Service A", "Server 1", "Database XYZ", etc.)
- The configuration item **type** (represented by either an icon or color -- not too important right now)
- Those things with the **least dependents** at the top

  - i.e. a service is represented by all the things that compose it -- applications, DBs, etc. and I'd like to have the hierarchy in order from services down.
- The **relationships** between all the elements, which **aren't strictly hierarchical**.

  - Multiple services could depend on one application
  - Multiple applications could depend on multiple databases which could depend on one database server.
- If possible, the ability to focus on one branch of the tree from top to bottom by clicking on it (though this can come *way* later)

Once I get my head around it, I'd like to set up something simple on GitHub and see if I can use D3 to help contribute to the world of IT Service Management.

### The Question

Philosophically, is D3 designed to support a visualization of this nature, and what is my best route to accomplish it?

Thanks!